# How to use output/artifact of one GitLab CI pipeline stage in subsequent stage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline that does 2 main things: 1) builds a static site using content from an external provider and 2) builds a docker container from that static site.

At the moment, I have these steps in 2 stages, and the build stage produces an artifact

```
stages:
    - build
    - package
  
build:
  stage: build
  image: node:12
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  artifacts: 
    untracked: true
    paths: 
      - folder/for/project
      - folder/that/was/not/there/before/build/time

package:
  stage: package
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  needs: 
    - build
  script:
    - export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375/
    - docker build -t my-project .
```

I can't get the package stage to see the built files though - the `docker build -t my-project` command will build a version where `folder/for/project` is present but `folder/that/was/not/there/before/build/time` is not. Downloading the artifact after the build step is completed does give me both folders, so clearly it is *exporting* the right stuff from that step and not *importing* it into the next.

The CI log for the package stage does say that it's downloading *something* but I can't tell where it goes or how to access it (someID and tokenHere match values seen in the upload artifacts bit of the build step)

```
Downloading artifacts for build (someID)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=someID responseStatus=200 OK token=tokenHere
```

How do I pass these files from one stage in my pipeline to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now managed to get this working, hopefully this will help someone else in the future. The issue was that I had named my jobs the same names as my stages (`build`, `test`, etc) so GitLab must have been getting confused. Using the example in the question, the working solution would be:

```
stages:
    - build
    - package
  
build-job:
  stage: build
  image: node:12
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  artifacts: 
    untracked: true
    paths: 
      - folder/for/project
      - folder/that/was/not/there/before/build/time

package:
  stage: package
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  dependencies: 
    - build-job
  script:
    - export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375/
    - docker build -t my-project .
```

Notice I've changed the `build` job to `build-job` and updated the dependency name, and the stage names have remained the same.